# Flex and Amazon Payments

Tags: apache-flex, e-commerce, billing

I am trying to get amazon payments working w/ my flex app, as shown here:
http://miti.pricope.com/2009/07/11/using-amazon-flexible-payment-system-with-flex/

I've done exactly as he says, I've downloaded the files & changed the access key & secret key. When I run it on localhost or my production server I get "Signature did not match"

What else do I need to get this to work?

Is there something else I need that he forgot to include?

Comment: Find out why these variables are different:

    $querystring and $_GET['signature']

Comment: Ok...where do I get the setSenderTokenId paramater that I need for PaySample.php? The ReadMe file included in the amazon files says I get this from CBUISample.php but that page doesn't return any sort of Token

Comment: The variables returned in your CBUISample.php file are as follows:
returnURL,
pipelineName,
callerKey,
version,
callerReference,
transactionAmount,
paymentReason,
signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try next:

goto return.and find `function validateQueryString()` and change to this:

```
function validateQueryString()
{
    echo "validing the query string now\n";
    $querystring = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    echo $querystring."\n";
    echo $_GET['signature'];
    $obj = new Amazon_FPS_CBUIUtils(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
    //Original signature received in response from Amazon FPS should be specified.
    $signatureMatched = $obj->validateQueryString($querystring,$_GET['signature']);

    if ($signatureMatched) {
        echo "signature matched \n";
  $request =  new Amazon_FPS_Model_PayRequest();
  //set the proper senderToken here.
  $request->setSenderTokenId($_GET['tokenID']);
  $amount = new Amazon_FPS_Model_Amount();
  $amount->setCurrencyCode("USD");
  //set the transaction amount here;
  $amount->setValue($_SESSION['transaction_amount']); 
  $request->setTransactionAmount($amount);
  //set the unique caller reference here.
  $request->setCallerReference($_GET['callerReference']); 
  $service = new Amazon_FPS_Client(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
                                        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
    invokePay($service, $request);
    }
    else
        echo "Signature did not match \n";
}
```

and post output here please, including your `Signature did not match`

Thanks.